# Codeigniter - Ordering active record alphabetically

Tags: codeigniter

I was wondering if someone could help me out with something.

I have a bit of ajax that calls a function in my model.

But i cant seem to be able to order the output by 'model'.

Below the function im having trouble with

```
function get_models_by_brand($tree = null)
{
    $this->db->select('id, model');

    if($tree != NULL){
        $this->db->where('brand_id', $tree);
    }

    $query = $this->db->get('models');
    $models = array();

    if($query->result()){
        foreach ($query->result() as $model) {
            $models[$model->id] = $model->model;
        }
        return $models;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Comment: `$this->db->order_by('model')`?

Answer (score 39):

[From the documentation](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html),

> **$this->db->order_by();**
>
> Lets you set an ORDER BY clause. The first parameter contains the name
> of the column you would like to order by. The second parameter lets
> you set the direction of the result. Options are asc or desc, or
> random.
>
> ```
> $this->db->order_by("title", "desc"); 
> // Produces: ORDER BY title DESC
> ```
>
> You can also pass your own string in the first parameter:
>
> ```
> $this->db->order_by('title desc, name asc'); 
> // Produces: ORDER BY title DESC, name ASC
> ```
>
> Or multiple function calls can be made if you need multiple fields.
>
> ```
> $this->db->order_by("title", "desc");
> $this->db->order_by("name", "asc"); 
> // Produces: ORDER BY title DESC, name ASC
> ```