# how to insert a row alphabetically in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have a table named `student_table`.

The table consists of three columns: `s_id, s_rollnum, s_name`.

I want to insert a new student to that table. While inserting, name should be sorted alphabetically and roll number also get sorted accordingly. Any idea?

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883848/codeigniter-ordering-active-record-alphabetically

Comment: I think if u firstly insert the s letter name the rollno assign next from the last  ... after s you add b letter name u have to update all records again

Comment: It doesn't matter if inserted rows exist alphabeticaly by name. It is up to getting those by selecting by name (ASC|DESC).

Answer (score 0):

You can sort column values alphabetically  easily by **$this->db->order_by();**

According to your table columns:
(s_id, s_rollnum, s_name)

```
$this->db->order_by('s_name ASC', 's_rollnum ASC');
```

You can also do it in multiple statements

```
$this->db->order_by('s_name', 'ASC');
$this->db->order_by('s_rollnum', 'ASC');
```

More info in the official [documentation](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)