# Sort results out by number ends or scores codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, sorting

On my controller and model function I am trying to sort the scoring

> Question: In the foreach below in model function how can I display it like if the scores are the same then it sorts it out by how many ends they have played

Currently it only sorts it out by the scores.

**CURRENT OUTPUT**

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [skip] => A
            [second] => B
            [lead] => C
            [score] => 65
            [ends] => 41
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [skip] => D
            [second] => E
            [lead] => F
            [score] => 65
            [ends] => 42
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [skip] => G
            [second] => H
            [lead] => I
            [score] => 52
            [ends] => 38
        )

)
```

[image]

Model function

```
public function getTriplesResults($event_id) {
    $data = array();

    $this->db->where('event_id', $event_id);
    $this->db->order_by('score', 'desc');
    $query = $this->db->get('triples');

    foreach ($query->result_array() as $result) {

        $data[] = array(
            'skip' => $result['skip'],
            'second' => $result['second'],
            'lead' => $result['lead'],
            'score' => $result['score'],
            'ends' => $result['ends']
        );
    }

    return $data;
}
```

Controller

```
<?php

class Results extends MX_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        //$this->load->model('catalog/tournament/event_model');
    }

    public function triples($event_id = "") {

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($this->getTriplesResults($event_id));
        echo "</pre>";
    }

    public function getTriplesResults($event_id) {
        $data = array();

        $this->db->where('event_id', $event_id);
        $this->db->order_by('score', 'asc');
        $query = $this->db->get('triples');

        foreach ($query->result_array() as $result) {

            $data[] = array(
                'skip' => $result['skip'],
                'second' => $result['second'],
                'lead' => $result['lead'],
                'score' => $result['score'],
                'ends' => $result['ends']
            );
        }

        return $data;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use: `$this->db->order_by('score desc, ends desc');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can adjust your query to order by two columns:

```
$this->db->order_by('score desc, ends desc');
```

OR

```
$this->db->order_by("score", "desc");
$this->db->order_by("ends", "desc");
```

More information here:
[Codeigniter - Ordering active record alphabetically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883848/codeigniter-ordering-active-record-alphabetically)